# jsonobject don't support index 0

Tags: json

I have this code in an android app, it take an array where each element is a string that contain the format of jsonObject, but i want to take the value of each object, so use it.The problem is the JsonObject don't take the index 0, so it stared in 1, and i never see the value 1 for the first object.

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(a[i]);
        g=jsonn.getString(TAG_ID);
        builder.append("\n"+i+"."+"id swicht: "+"\n"+g+"\n");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {//e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: Your code looks all messed up

Comment: I think we need more context.  What type of array is a and how is it being populated?

Comment: The array type is String, at first i receive a string like this:    [{"dpid":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0c"},{"dpid":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0d"},{"dpid":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:09"},{"dpid":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0a"}], then i convert this in array using split with ',' caracter.This array is that i refer in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the code should be:

```
jsonStr = jsonStr.substring(1, jsonStr.length() - 1); // (remove the "[" and "]")
String[] a = jsonStr.split(",");
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonn = new JSONObject(a[i]);
        g = jsonn.getString(TAG_ID);
        builder.append("\n"+i+"."+"id swicht: "+"\n"+g+"\n");
    } catch (JSONException e) {//e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

If you don't do the first line, the first and last elem in array will be misformat and cannot be convert JSONObject -- "[{"dpid":"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:0c"}" is not a well format for JSONObject.